# Android tab activity strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a tabactivity, from it when I start another activity then this activity is getting destroyed.

Now this happens on one device whereas on other its working fine.
If due to bad luck there comes no soln for this, then is there any workaround ?

I am detecting the home activity destroy as an exit from app.

Comment: When you start a new activity the old one might be destroyed by the system, it's normal behavior. Also, don't use the deprecated `TabActivity`.

Comment: I also think it's this case only, is there any way by which I can detect app exit ?

Answer (score 0):

Well it was a rare issue, the device was having too many google account and apps, when reset its working ok. It was a memory issue i think.